# SOAP web-services with security header

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap

I am going to implement SOAP web-services with a security header for my Java EE project. I am developing the server side application, where I have to validate the header. I am going to do this job for the first time. Can any one provide some valuable idea for this and help me? Any help is welcome.

Comment: What exactly is the 'security header' (SOAP, HTTP, JMS header)?

Answer (score 5):

If security is being implemented in the HTTP header, then you can get map of the HTTP headers from the message context (returned from WebServiceContext.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS)).

There is a good intro tutorial here: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/application-authentication-with-jax-ws/

Alternatively, the WS-Security standard implements authentication information in the SOAP header.  Validation can be accomplished by writing a SOAPHandler that is deployed on the endpoint.  You can find an example here: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2335032&tstart=15